# parse yaml file to find duplicate values using python

Tags: python, parsing, yaml

I have the below Yaml File

```
Tests:
 - Test:
    test_name: Test_Name1
    test_id: 1
    test_desc: Test Name1
 - Test:
    test_name: Test_Name2
    test_id: 2
    test_desc: Test Name2
 - Test:
    test_name: Test_Name1
    test_id: 3
    test_desc: Test Name3
```

I have to raise an alert if any of test_name having repeated value. For example in above case since Test_Name1 is repeated this will raise an alert. test_name and test_id should be having unique values in the file. 
I have tried converting yaml to dictionary and then finding out duplicated value, this shows error as TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'.

Below are my code

```
import yaml

mapping = {}
stream = open('C:/modelsData/work/tests.yaml', 'r')
data = yaml.load(stream)
for key in data:
    mapping.setdefault(data[key], set()).add(key)
print(mapping)
result = filter(lambda x: len(x)>1, mapping.values())
print("Duplicated Values ", list(result))
```

Please note - I can not remove "-" from yaml file. vasically I can not change anything on file, this is to be done via code. :)

Comment: `for key in data:` iterates over a single value, `"Tests"`; `data[key]` is a list. You don't need to change the YAML structure, but you do need to know what it parses to.

Comment: for key in data:
    mapping[key] = []
    mapping[key].extend(data[key]) -- also did not worked as expected

Comment: @jonrsharpe    for key, value in data.items():
    mapping.setdefault(value, set()).add(key) -- this also didn't worked out

Comment: I would strongly recommend basic debugging - maybe add `print`s to see what you're actually working with. If you're unfamiliar with YAML syntax, make sure you understand the actual shape of that data.

Comment: do you want to remove the duplicates or just show a message which one is duplicated. add the expected output

Comment: @komatiraju032 Message would be fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print the result of the conversion and play with it, try to get to the result one step at a time. That is how I came up with this:

```
import yaml

stream = open('save_text.txt', 'r')
data = yaml.load(stream, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)

t_list = data["Tests"]

spot_duplicates = {}
for test in t_list:

    if test["Test"]["test_name"] not in spot_duplicates:
        spot_duplicates[test["Test"]["test_name"]] = 1
    else:
        spot_duplicates[test["Test"]["test_name"]] += 1

for dup in spot_duplicates:
    if spot_duplicates[dup] > 1:
        print("Duplicated value", dup)
```